# In C++, where are static, dynamic and local variables stored? How about in C and Java?

Tags: java, c++, c

In C++, where are static, dynamic and local variables stored? How about in C and Java?

Comment: And how about LISP, FORTRAN and Haskell? Ooh, and what about PHP and Perl?

Comment: You forgot brainfuck and whitespace...

Comment: `static` means similar, but subtly different things in those languages.  `local` and `dynamic` are not orthogonal concepts.  So it's difficult to answer this question accurately without knowing how much you already know about the subject.  Perhaps if you explained more clearly what you want to know you could get a better answer.

Comment: Are you looking at how they are written in the standard, or in certain implementations?

Comment: They are stored in an implementation defined manner.

Comment: This question is too broad. Storage of variables is implementation dependent. More importantly, these languages have different meanings for the terms static, local, and dynamic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're compiling C/C++ to create a windows executable (or maybe for any x86 system) then static and global variables are usually stored in a segment of the memory called a data segment. This memory is usually also divided to variables which are initialized and those that are not initialized by the program in their definition.

Local variables which are defined inside a functions are allocated on the running stack of the program, alongside the return address of the function.

By "dynamic" I'm assuming you mean things allocated using `new` or `malloc`. These are usually stored in yet another area of memory called "the heap" (which has nothing to do with the "heap" data structure)

All these details are highly platform dependent and usually, as a programmer you would not need to even be aware of them.

Comment: Sure. Most definitely any C/C++ "programmer" worth their mettle knows where their variables are stored. It comes with the territory. For managed languages, one can argue otherwise, but not for C/C++.

Comment: I'd say it's nearly always useful to be *aware* of how the constructs you work with are implemented (see Joel Spolsky's "The Law of Leaky Abstractions" article for more discussion of this point).  But for most day-to-day activities, it's probably more *useful* to think of things at the higher level of abstraction.

Comment: I suppose there's a useful reason to know about stack variables- If you run into an unexpected stack overflow but without any infinite recursion, one place to look for are large definitions of local variables.

Comment: You should be aware of where your data is allocated because there can be large performance differences; unless performance is irrelevant I guess.

Comment: @mrjoltcola Absolutely right! Since novice programmers who frequently skipping memory part during programming lectures are missing a critical part of the programming itself. (Esepcially C/C++) Hell, I know people from my previous college whom had no intention of learning about memory structure and later, couldn't create an efficient and stable program due to bunch of memory leaks and unsecured checkflags.

Answer (score 2):

**C, C++**

- Static: Data segment of the module/dll/shared library the code is compiled into.
- Dynamic: On any memory heap, such as the C runtime heap, Win32 heap, custom heaps. Which heap the data ends up on depends on how you allocate the memory (and for C++, if operator new/delete are overridden to use a specific allocator).
- Local: On the stack frame for the current function/method.

**Java**

- Static: On the JVM heap.
- Dynamic: On the JVM heap.
- Local: On the stack frame for the current function/method.

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment